# Required props for List and Edit components in route when using CustomApp

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to upgrade a custom app from admin-on-rest to react-admin (v2.15). After I figured out that the `declareResources` action was "replaced" by `registerResource` most seemed ok, but I still struggle with the List and Edit components route definitions that complains about missing required props (compared to what props are defined in [the custom app documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html%22the%20documentation%22)).

If I define a List component like this it works fine:

```
<Route exact path="/mystuffs" render={(routeProps) => <MystuffList hasCreate hasEdit hasShow={false} hasList resource="mystuffs" basePath="/mystuffs" {...routeProps} />} />
```

Similar the only way I can get an Edit-component to work is to pass the required props like so:

```
<Route exact path="/mystuffs/:id" render={(routeProps) => <MystuffEdit resource="mystuffs" id={routeProps.match.params.id} basePath="/mystuffs" {...routeProps} />} />
```

But to me it seems a bit tedious to define all of these props (i.e was not required with admin-on-rest). Is this the correct way of doing it or am I missing something obvious here since [the custom app documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html%22the%20documentation%22) doesn't specify all of the required props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed required. We have still a lot of work to do on the custom app side, including documentation.

You can help us! Can you explain why you needed to use react-admin this way? What wasn't possible using the default Admin? etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do. For now I have added a custom resource component that works for me so far. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/activist/18b170f4bc3859fe2a490ae2dfc4b50f

Comment: I forgot to answer your question as to why we use react-admin like this. The answer is for legacy reasons. When we started out there were issues like rerendering of children in WithPermissions etc that made us choose to implement it as a custom app at that time as well as other internal reasons. I think that by now it would be possible to change it to using default set up.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up adding a custom resource component that is pretty similar to the Resource in react-admin. Something like this:

```
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


const RACustomResource = ({ resource, list, edit, create, show, path, children, ...rest }) => {
  const { computedMatch, ...options } = rest;

  const listResource = list ?
  (<Route
    exact
    path={path}
    render={(routeProps) => {
      const { staticContext, ...routeOpts } = routeProps;
      return React.createElement(list, {
        basePath: path || routeProps.match.url,
        resource,
        hasCreate: !!create,
        hasList: !!list,
        hasEdit: !!edit,
        hasShow: !!show,
        ...routeOpts,
        ...options,
      });
    }}
  />)
  : null;

  const createResource = create ?
    (<Route
      path={`${path}/create`}
      render={(routeProps) => {
        const { staticContext, ...routeOpts } = routeProps;
        return React.createElement(create, {
          basePath: path || routeProps.match.url,
          resource,
          hasList: !!list,
          hasShow: !!show,
          record: {},
          ...routeOpts,
          ...options,
        });
      }}
    />)
    : null;

  const editResource = edit ?
    (<Route
      exact
      path={`${path}/:id`}
      render={(routeProps) => {
        const { staticContext, ...routeOpts } = routeProps;
        return React.createElement(edit, {
          basePath: path || routeProps.match.url,
          resource,
          hasCreate: !!create,
          hasList: !!list,
          hasEdit: !!edit,
          hasShow: !!show,
          id: routeProps.match.params.id,
          ...routeOpts,
          ...options,
        });
      }}
    />)
    : null;

  const showResource = show ?
    (<Route
      exact
      path={`${path}/:id/show`}
      render={(routeProps) => {
        const { staticContext, ...routeOpts } = routeProps;
        return React.createElement(show, {
          basePath: path || routeProps.match.url,
          resource,
          hasCreate: !!create,
          hasList: !!list,
          hasEdit: !!edit,
          hasShow: !!show,
          id: routeProps.match.params.id,
          ...routeOpts,
          ...options,
        });
      }}
    />)
    : null;

  return (
    <Switch>
      {createResource}
      {showResource}
      {editResource}
      {listResource}
      {children}
    </Switch>
  );
};

RACustomResource.propTypes = {
  resource: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  path: PropTypes.string,
  basePath: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.any,
  list: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),
  create: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),
  edit: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),
  show: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),

};

export default RACustomResource;


// used like this
// <RACustomResource path="/myresource" resource="myresource" list={MyResourceList} create={MyResourceCreate} edit={MyResourceEdit} />
```